# Cannot install APK Release version

Tags: android, react-native

I have problem installing react native android application in real device. I once installed the debug mode and it went well. Everything fine. Then I uninstalled the application. After that, I create the release APK and try to install it and failed. Then I try with `./gradlew installRelease` command from android studio and I get something like this

Install release log

> Execution failed for task ':app:installRelease'.
>
> > com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION: Package com.yumboxapp attempting to redeclare permission com.yumboxapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE already owned by com.yumboxapp

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.yumboxapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@drawable/icon"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <service
        android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.MessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.InstanceIdService" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

  <!--add FacebookActivity-->
  <activity tools:replace="android:theme"
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
    <!-- <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/> -->

  <!--add CustomTabActivity-->
  <activity
    android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
    android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>

  <!--reference your fb_app_id-->
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/fb_app_id"/>

  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="api_key_here"/>
  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Anyone can help ?

Device info:
Asus Zenfone 2 ZE551ML

Android Version: 5.0

Comment: please put your AndroidManifest code.

Comment: I have put the android manifest. Thanks

Comment: are you sure that you removed dev app from your device?

Comment: Yes i’m reallys sure. Even I install the debug version again, try it and it works, and uninstall the debug version again. And then I try install the release version, still failed to install

Comment: @KevinDave have you solved this issue? I have the same one on the same device